# implementing a write method for binary I/O

Tags: java, io, binary

I'm trying to do java binary I/O where I write a read and a write function with the given headers. I got the read function to work but here is the spec for the write function.

Now, using the `DataOutputStream` class in the Java Standard Library, complete the write method so that it writes the values in the specified `ArrayList<Object>` to a file. The list should only contain `Integer` and `Double` objects - if you encounter any other type of object you should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (a Java Standard Library exception). In addition, there should only be well-formed `Integer`-`Double` groups, i.e., one `Integer` object that specifies how many `Double` objects follow. If you have missing or extra `Double` values you should also throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. You can test your write method by using your well tested read method and seeing if you get the expected results. You can test you logic for throwing IllegalArgumentExceptions by constructing `ArrayList<Object>` lists with unexpected types or ill-formed int-double groups.

here is the code....

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinaryReader
{
   private String filename;
   private ArrayList<Object> list;

   public static ArrayList<Object> read(String fileName)
   {
      FileInputStream in = null;
      ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

      try
      {
         in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("File not found");
      }

      DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(in);

      boolean read = true;
      int number = 0;
      double dbl = 0;

      while(read)
      {
         try
         {
            number = data.readInt();
         }
         catch(EOFException e)
         {
            System.out.println("Caught end of file exception");
            break;
         }
         catch(IOException e)
         {
            System.out.println("Caught");
         }

         list.add(number);

         for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
         {
            try
            {
               dbl = data.readDouble();
            }
            catch(EOFException e)
            {
               System.out.println("Caught");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
               System.out.println("Caught");
            }

            list.add(dbl);
         }
      }
      return list;
   }

   public static void write(String fileName, ArrayList<Object> list)
   {
      FileOutputStream out = null;

      try
      {
         out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("file not found");
      }

      DataOutputStream data = new DataOutputStream(out);
      //int count = 0;
      try
      {//PROBLEM AREAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
         for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
         {
            data.writeInt((Integer)list.get(i));


            for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
            {
               data.writeDouble((Double)list.get(i));
            }
         }
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Caught");
      }


   }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? What is your program doing wrong? What do you expect it to output and what is it actually outputting?

Comment: This is your problem area: `for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) { data.writeDouble((Double)list.get(i)); }`.  Your bounds are wrong, you don't want to write the *whole* list in here.  Also, you probably want to use `j` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check for invalid object can be done by using instanceof :

```
if((!(list.get(i) instanceof Integer) || !(list.get(i) instanceof Double)){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only integer and Double Allowed");
}
```

For integer-double pair check once you get an Integer treat its value as expected count, then have an actual count, in following iteration before you encounter Integer again keep incrementing your actual count, when you encounter Integer again check if acutal count == expected count if not, throw exception else reinitialize expectedCount with the new Integer value.